# sp_executesql output parameter incorrect value

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm getting different result for outputParam from fallowing two queries. The first one is generated by entity framework and it gives 0 for outputParam. For the second result is 5.

```
declare @p2 int
set @p2=0
exec sp_executesql N'usp_GetOrders @order_date, @output_param',N'@order_date datetime,@output_param int output',@order_date='2015-05-07 12:37:14.579',@output_param=@p2 output
select @p2 AS outputParam

declare @p2 int
set @p2=0
exec [dbo].[usp_GetOrders] @order_date='2015-05-07 12:37:14.579',@output_param=@p2 output
select @p2 AS outputParam
```

Procedure looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetOrders]
    @order_date AS datetime,
    @output_param AS int OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT @output_param=5

    SELECT  o.Id
    FROM    dbo.[Order] o
    WHERE   OrderDate > @order_date

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are missing `output` when calling the procedure using `sp_executesql`.

```
exec sp_executesql N'usp_GetOrders @order_date, @output_param output',N'@order_date datetime,@output_param int output',@order_date='2015-05-07 12:37:14.579',@output_param=@p2 output
```

Your direct procedure call is correct, what is why it is returning the correct value. If you call your procedure without `output`, it will return `0` as well.

```
exec [dbo].[usp_GetOrders] @order_date='2015-05-07 12:37:14.579',@output_param=@p2
```

Comment: Where do I miss "output", procedure should return 5 for @output_param

Comment: The sp_executesql doesn't have `@output_param OUTPUT` when calling the procedure `usp_GetOrders @order_date, @output_param`. The way you called procedure (second procedure call) is correct